# Java - Flicker when using repaint()

Tags: java, graphics, repaint, flicker

Hello I i'm having random flicker every couple of seconds when running my program, it has a single image moving across screen. I'm using Graphics paint() method and repaint() in the thread's run() method. Here are the relevant parts of the code, i'll post entire code if necessary. Btw, pawns is an arraylist loaded with pawn objects, originally I had 5 threads for 5 images moving across but I tried with only 1 image and it still flickers so it's not that.

```
private BufferedImage helicopter;

helicopter = ImageIO.read(new File("white.png"));

public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
      for(count=0; count<pawns.size(); count++){
         g.drawImage(helicopter, pawns.get(count).getX(), pawns.get(count).getY(), null);
      }
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawLine(350, 0, 350, 600);
   }

public void run() {
         while(true) {
            randSleep = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            randMove = (int)(Math.random()*2);
            pawn.setX(pawn.getX()+randMove);
            try{
               Thread.sleep(40);
            } 
            catch(Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }

            repaint();

         }
      }
```

Comment: You should call `super.paint(g)` before doing anything else in the `paint` method. If your class is a subclass of `JComponent`, use its `paintComponent` method instead of `paint` and make a call to `super.paintComponent(g)`. Additionally, since `java.awt.Component` and its subclasses implement `ImageObserver`, why don't you replace `null` with the reference in the call to `drawImage`?

Comment: You'll probably need double buffering.

Comment: I cannot use paintComponent because I'm using jFrame, sure I could create a jpanel then use paintcomponent on it and I might try that later. On the other hand I implemented doublebuffering but it doesn't work, flicker is still there.

Comment: `I cannot use paintComponent because I'm using jFrame,` - you should NOT be using the JFrame for the custom painting. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComonent() method of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. Swing is double buffered by default, which is why you should use this approach. Do it right the first time instead of "trying it later".

Answer (score 2):

> On components with complex output, repaint() should be invoked with
>   arguments which define only the rectangle that needs updating, rather
>   than the no-arg version, which causes the entire component to be
>   repainted.
>
> Swing's implementation of paint() factors the call into 3 separate
>   callbacks: paintComponent() paintBorder() paintChildren() Extensions
>   of Swing components which wish to implement their own paint code
>   should place this code within the scope of the paintComponent() method
>   ( not within paint()).

[source: Painting in AWT and Swing: Good Painting Code Is the Key to App Performance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

You should notice in the source quoted and linked that repaint() (no arguments) will call update(), which by default clears the background before drawing.  I suspect that this is the source of the flicker, when the component is cleared before calling paint().

If you are using Swing components you should not implement your own double buffering but instead use the functionality provided by Swing.

First try, calling a repaint with arguments to avoid update clearing the entire background. Or write an override for the update method.  If that does not solve the problem next try putting your drawing code in the paintComponent method of a Swing component.